# dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction> why sometime you have to precise the Action?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I get a problem, probably because I' trying some thing new with typescript (type redux stuff),

That's my error message : `Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => Promise<string>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.  TS2345`

The thing here is I don't really understand why I got this error because typeScript just throw the error on this one and not on the other so I quite perplexe.

My code (with the error) :

```
/Action/userAction.js
___________________________________________________
export const signOut = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(UserSignoutAction());
    dispatch(InitialErase());
    dispatch(signOutSessionInitial());
    dispatch(isLogout());
    persistor.flush();
    return "done";
  } catch (e) {
    const error = await e;
    throw error;
  }
};

/NavBar/container.js
_______________________________________________
const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: Dispatch
): {
  signOut: () => Promise<String>;
} => ({
  signOut: () => dispatch(signOut()),
});
```

This example throw an error I can fix with `signOut: () => dispatch<any>(signOut()),`
I could understand that I need to type the dispatch ok (but don't know what I need to but currently that why I put an any)

other code (without error):

```
/Action/userAction.js
___________________________________________________
export const sessionInitial = (
  session_id: number
): sessionInitialActionOption => ({
  type: SESSION,
  payload: session_id
});

/Dashboard/container.js
_______________________________________________
const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: Dispatch
): {
  sessionInitial: (
    session_id: number
  ) => {
    type: string;
    payload: number;
  };
} => ({
  sessionInitial: (session_id: number) => dispatch(sessionInitial(session_id))
});
```

I guess my mistake is that I would like to execute more than one `Actions Creator` through a function. I think that not the good way to do that, or this solution is ok but is ridiculous to put/call inside `mapDispatchToProps`.

Thanks for helping me to understand how this part work it's quite complexe.

---

___________________________Solution?____________________________

---

I found the solution thx to Hassan Naqvi's hint! The following code work for me :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<
    void,
    void,
    | UserActionsType            //one of my actionsType
    | sessionActionsType         //one of my actionsType
    | isConnectActionsType       //one of my actionsType
    | initialUserActionsType     //one of my actionsType
  >
): {
  signOut: () => void;
} => ({
  signOut: () => dispatch(signOut())
});
```

or

```
type ApplicationDispatch = ThunkDispatch<IStoreState, void, AnyAction> & Dispatch

const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: ApplicationDispatch
): {
  signOut: () => void;
} => ({
  signOut: () => dispatch(signOut())
});

export default compose<any>(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
);
```

I don't really understand  why that work and not the step above... But I ll still try to understand why `redux-thunk`? and why `Dispatch` from `redux` is not enough (probably because actionsType included/send with the function `ThunkDispatch`)  why don't just replace the 'any' `signOut: () => dispatch<any>(signOut())`by the actionsType ?  (not working for me)

What is the difference between `Dispatch` and `ThunkDispatch`?

Thx everyone for reading this post hopefully I'll read some posts who's gonna change my life! be indulgent guys. Have a good day !

---

[image]

-As you see above, when you use redux-thunk to handle asynchronous actions, the action reaches the inner most function, actionFunction, which is responsible for executing the action. But this dispatch is something which we create in the middleware, and it is not the dispatch from the createStore, which has listeners and passes the values to the reducer.

-The dispatch to reducer happens from it parent function which is nextFunction.

(source : https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/understanding-how-redux-thunk-works-72de3bdebc50)

other useful link : https://daveceddia.com/what-is-a-thunk/

So if I really understand what happen, ThunkDispatch is able to execute fct,  async fct or not at the exception of Dispatch. Dispatch is calling `Actions Creator` to reducers.

If I miss understand something tell me and I ll correct it.

Hopefully it's gonna help you a little bit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are using the type `Dispatch` for your first argument in `mapDispatchToProps`.

Since you are using `redux-thunk` you need to use the `ThunkDispatch` type imported from `redux-thunk`.

So your NavBar/container.ts should become:

```
import { AnyAction } from "redux";
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';

// ApplicationState is the shape of your redux store.
// You can use any but its recommended to have a specified shape
// This should ideally be in a different file since it could be needed in many places
interface ApplicationState {
   username: string;
   userId: string;
}

// Use ApplicationDispatch everywhere instead of Dispatch
type ApplicationDispatch = ThunkDispatch<ApplicationState, void, AnyAction> & Dispatch

const mapDispatchToProps = (
  dispatch: ApplicationDispatch
): {
  signOut: () => Promise<String>;
} => ({
  signOut: () => dispatch(signOut()),
});
```

Comment: ok but It's because I used dispatch in the function ? when i replace everything I got ```Generic type 'ThunkDispatch<S, E, A>' requires 3 type argument(s).  TS2314``` what should I do ? I do not understand very well do you have some docs or can you explain to me ?

Comment: just for test I do ```dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>``` but got following : ```Type '(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => void' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<String>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally  TS2739```

Comment: Ok I found the solution Thx to your hint ! But I thing I don't really understand it ...

Comment: Thx for editied your post but I don't understand what is ```ApplicationState is the shape of your state.``` is that the ```Store```Shape ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it. The shape of the redux store. For example: Your redux state may contain something like: `interface ApplicationState { username: string, password: string }`. You can use the ApplicationState interface there